# Set Action to menu item from main menu where actions are methods in Different view controllers

Tags: macos, menu, program-entry-point

I have 4 viewcontrollers ,so how can i link  various actions from each viewcontrollers to Main menu menu items, i have done by creating menu items in each conttroller but menu item vanishes after it is closed